# Software to monitor disk space and send email on threshold

Tags: server, software-recommendation, disk-usage, log, system-monitor

I'm looking for something that can monitor disk usage on my partitions and send an email alert when threshold is reached. For example, when sdb1 has 10 % disk space left it will send an email to me. It would be nice if it has some more advanced configuration options as well. Alert me if the disk is filling up quickly and such.

I don't want logs sent to me on a daily/weekly etc. basis, just when the threshold is reached.

Answer (score 3):

Figured I should let others know how this turned out. I've been using [monit [image: Install monit]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/monit) for the last couple of months and it is more than sufficient and can send out emails when a disk hits a certain threshold.